# Image css max width without distort

Tags: image, css

Goody, Would like to know how can i stretch the image to fit the width, without distort the height? maybe display the center part of the image only? This is the website:

http://youthicons.my/2013/11/lorem-ipsum-dolar-sit-amet/

and the portion of css:

```
.featured-image, .featured-img{ top: 0; width: 100%; height: 537px; left: 0;}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`height: auto;` instead of `height: 537px` on the actual image.

If you don't want it to grow quite so large, you can set height on the div and set `overflow: hidden;'

Comment: Thanks a lot! it did the fix. would like to know how to show the middle part of the image? it doesn't work with verticle align, Thx!

Comment: Add a negative `margin-top` to the image. You will likely need to use media-queries in order to get the image where you want at different widths.You can also use `width: auto; max-width: 100%` on the image if you don't want it get bigger than the actual width.